# Who maintains the openjdk binaries for old versions, which are accessible through homebrew-core?

Tags: java, homebrew, java-11

I know that Oracle does not provide updates and security patches for older java versions like: openjdk8, openjdk11 etc. But we can install the openjdk using homebrew which is specified through formula files on homebrew-core github repository.

Links: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/o/openjdk%408.rb
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/o/openjdk%4011.rb

Now, I am unable to understand (and find elsewhere) whether these jdk builds are outdated or are being updated with the latest security patches etc.

It is hard to believe that these are outdated because these are being used extensively/vastly across the industry.

In case of second option, where these are being updated regularly. Then my question is who is updating and maintaining those? If this is part of Openjdk project's process itself (which is open to all collaborators and the individual collaborators are contributing), but finally who is providing the binary build here? These individual collaborators can not provide the build here.

Answer (score 1):

> Oracle does not provide updates and security patches for older java versions

Incorrect. Oracle supports older versions of their JDK products for many years, across decades. For several of those years, updates are made available to the public. For even more years, those updates are made available to their paid customers. For example, paid customers receive support for Java 8 at least through 2030.

Do not confuse the various Java products offered by Oracle:

- [*Oracle JDK*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) product is Oracle’s mainstream, supported implementation of Java. Different versions of this product have had varying terms of use, some with a fee required.
- Oracle also offers a direct build of the codebase at OpenJDK in a product whose name never quite seems to be clearly established. This naming problem causes some confusion in the marketplace. This product is *not* supported by Oracle.
- [*GraalVM*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM) is a specialized implementation of Java. One edition is available free of cost, another is a commercial product. Oracle is currently in the process of transferring much of the source code to the OpenJDK project.

By the way, Oracle is but one of several vendors offering JDK products (binaries, installers). Others include Microsoft, Amazon, Adoptium of the Eclipse Foundation, BellSoft, Azul Systems, Red Hat, IBM, SAP, and more. Some of these products are available free of cost, some require a fee with a support plan. Some of these vendors continue to provide maintenance releases of their JDK 8 products. For example Adoptium right now is preparing October 2023 releases of binaries for Eclipse Temurin 8u392 & 11.0.21.

All of these vendors utilize the open-source codebase housed at the collaborative [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project that implements the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). Understand that the OpenJDK project produces only source code, not binaries/installers. This source code is maintained on a voluntary basis by the members of the OpenJDK consortium and other donors, under the leadership of Oracle.

From skimming your linked script, it seems that Homebrew is sourcing JDK 7 products from [Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems). For JDK 8, I am unable to decipher that script except to say that it *might* be that Homebrew is actually compiling directly the source code obtained from the OpenJDK site — but I am not sure. At any rate, regarding policies for updates, you should be asking the Homebrew support, not Stack Overflow.

---

You might consider using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) for installing/uninstalling JDK products (and similar software kit products). This clever collection of shell scripts makes easy work of listing, downloading, and installing JDK products from your choice of several vendors who choose to submit data describing their product offerings.

Comment: I also know about the OracleJDK, for which Oracle provides support. Here, I am more keen to know about the openjdk distributions (not the oraclejdk) and that too specifically for - what is available on homebrew. 
But, thanks anyway for pointing out the Azul Systems here. For that also, if we see for the openjdk11 link, for Intel based Mac systems it is referring to https://jdk.java.net/archive/ which is I suppose owned by Oracle itself. So, the question remains same again. 
Please let me know if I am missing something here in understanding.